# Reverting LVM to separate partitions

Tags: vmware-esxi, lvm

I have an VMWare Virtual Machine (Ubuntu Server 11.04) that's using three VMDKs, then all of them are parte of an LVM.

The problem I'm facing is at the creation time every one of those VMDKs were created as Thin provisioning and two have reached the physical size, causing ESXi to force the stopping of the VM.

I would like to know if is there a way to remove the disks from the LVM (without mounting them), to delete some files, then shrink the VMDKs.

Answer (score 0):

The datastore ran out of space? You can add more physical storage and increase the datastore. Expect I/O errors and stopped VMs until you do.

With enough space to mount the file systems you can delete those files.

To resize the physical volumes to something realistic for the disks there is [pvresize](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/natty/en/man8/pvresize.8.html). There are limitations, in particular:

> pvresize will refuse to  shrink  PhysicalVolume  if  it  has  allocated
>          extents  after  where  its  new  end would be.

And you cannot reduce the VMDK until the PV is reduced or you lose data.  A pvmove to new disks and  vgreduce the old one will migrate off it however.